# Reduce WPF View Model boiler plate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the code pattern below repeated numerous times throughout my WPF application's view models. Is there any quick and easy way to reduce it, without resorting to aspect oriented programming or the like?

```
private string _scriptExecutionStage;
public string ScriptExecutionStage
{
    get => _scriptExecutionStage;
    set
    {
        if (value != _scriptExecutionStage)
        {
            _scriptExecutionStage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ScriptExecutionStage"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can - indeed - reduce the boilerplate code for properties. Alas, this does not come without cost, which is deriving your viewmodels from a `ViewModelBase` class

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (AreEqual(field, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        field = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In your `ViewModelBase` class you can define the `SetValue` method as presented. Basically you pass the reference to your backing field and operate with this reference. The logic stays the same.

In your property you can now just do

```
public string ScriptExecutionStage
{
    get => _scriptExecutionStage;
    set => SetValue(ref _scriptExecutionStage, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `SetProperty<T>(...)` in your `ViewModelBase` like.

```
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T propertyToSet, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName=null)
    {
        if(!propertyToSet.Equals(value))
        {
            propertyToSet = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```